# On select drop down "on change", not able to reset already selected options before setting new option as selected

Tags: jquery

I am a user list and on changing this drop down i want to set the selected attribute to currently selected option in the list and remove selected for all other options. But for some reason it is not working as expected.

Below is my code:

```
var sel_val_1 = jQuery('#' + id_1 + ' option:selected').val();
jQuery('#'+id_1+' option[value="'+sel_val_1+'"]').attr("selected","selected");
```

Whenver i run this on "on change" the option is getting selected but previous option is not getting reset. I tried below code to reset but it is also not helping.

```
jQuery('#'+id_1).get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
```

My main issue when doing on change there should be only one item as selected="selected" but whenever i select any item it gets the same attribute.

This is what i am getting:

```
<select style="width:260px;" name="employee_id" id="employee_id">
                                                    <option value="1" selected="selected">None </option>
                                                    <option value="4246" selected="selected">Name 1</option>
                                                    <option value="3441" selected="selected">Name 2</option>
                                                    <option value="4227">Name 3</option>
                                                    <option value="4479">Name 4</option>
                                                    <option value="4275">Name 5</option>
                                                    <option value="4506">Name 6</option>
                                            </select>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so you are selecting the already selected option ? Not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Also does the `select` have the `multiple` property set ?

Comment: when you select any value from a select box previous selected values are already got un-selected. So don't know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: no multiple set in drop down.... i just want to reset already selected options in that drop-down before setting new value as selected.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to run something like

```
 jQuery('#employee_id').find(":selected").attr('selected', false);
```

before you set the new option to `selected`.

**EDIT**

I played around a little in JSFiddle and came up with this.

```js
$('#employee_id').change(function () {
  $(this).children('[selected="selected"]').attr('selected', false);
  $(this).find('[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').attr('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="width:260px;" name="employee_id" id="employee_id">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">None </option>
  <option value="4246" selected="selected">Name 1</option>
  <option value="3441" selected="selected">Name 2</option>
  <option value="4227">Name 3</option>
  <option value="4479">Name 4</option>
  <option value="4275">Name 5</option>
  <option value="4506">Name 6</option>
</select>
```